# How to have sidebar links to other wikis with similar articles?

Tags: mediawiki

Sometimes Wikipedia or some other non-Wikimedia Foundation wiki will have an article with the same page title, about the same subject but from a different perspective.

Like Wikipedia does for articles in other language versions. How to have links appear at the bottom of the sidebar when another wiki (from a selection) has an article with the same title?

e.g. An article on the local wiki called Ethernet will then have links to [Wikipedia](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/EtherNet) and [Altera Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet), while an article called Prototype X-37 doesn't because there is no such page on those wikis.

Comment: Not trying to be a smartie-pants, but this sounds like you need your programmer hat. There are no mechanisms that I am aware of for this. Just make sure you do not grab your tin-foil hat- that is for listening to Jesse Ventura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the [functionality](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki#Interwiki_links_to_other_languages) built into Wikipedia you would have to have all of the Wikis belong to the same [Wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family).

Since your local Wiki is unlikely to be part of the Wikipedia family you could instead solve this with JavaScript, CSS and templates.

As an example creating a sidebar link to Wikipedia would require:

1. Create a template (e.g. `Template:iwWikipedia`) with:

   ```
   <div class="interProject wikipedia" style="display:none;">[//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{{1|{{PAGENAMEE}}}}} Wikipedia]</div>
   ```
2. Add the following to your `MediaWiki:Common.css`

   ```
   ul.interProject { 
     list-style: none;
     padding-left: 0; 
     margin-left: 0;
   }

   li.interProject,
   /* for Vector skin since the above doesn't take for some reason */
   #mw-panel div.portal div.body ul.interProject li.interProject { 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: left center;
     padding-left: 18px; 
     margin-left: 0;
   }

   li.wikipedia {
     background-image: url("//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png/14px-Wikipedia-logo.png");
   }
   ```
3. Add the following to your `MediaWiki:Common.js`

   ```
   /**
    * Adds interwikilinks to other projects in the left sidebar.
    */
   $( function() { 
       var iwlinks = jQuery( 'div.interProject' );
       if ( iwlinks.length > 0 ) {
           var pproject = jQuery( '#p-tb' ).clone().attr( 'id', 'p-project' ).insertAfter( '#p-tb' );
           pproject.find( 'h3' ).attr( 'id', 'p-project-label' ).text( 'On other projects' );
           pproject.find( 'ul' ).addClass( 'interProject' ).empty().append( iwlinks );
           iwlinks.replaceWith( function() {
               return $( '<li></li>' ).addClass( $(this).attr( 'class' ) ).append( $(this).contents() );
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Now adding {{iwWikipedia}} anywhere in your Ethernet article will add a link to the Ethernet article on English Wikipedia. If the articles don't have the same name simply add the desired name as an extra parameter e.g. {{iwWikipedia|Hello_World}} (with spaces replaced by underscores).

Comment: Wow, great answer! This ought to be a MediaWiki extension. Thanks.